# Comparing two models optimized over multiple parameters

Tags: optimization, model-selection, model-comparison, hyperparameter

Say you want to explore the effects of some binary parameter $X_0\in\{0, 1\}$ on the fitness $f$ of a model $M$. Now $M$ has other parameters $X_i$.

I've found a paper that optimizes $M$ against $f$ on all $X_i$ with $X_0 = 0$, and compares that with $M$ optimized against $f$ on all $X_i$ with $X_0 = 1$. Naturally, the optimized values of $X_i$ do not match between the two models.

I feel that this does not isolate the effect of $X_0$, but allows more complex interaction between model parameters, and that a fairer comparison would be an "all-else-being-equal" comparison with all the $X_i$ set to the same value. But... in a sense it is because of the values of $X_0$ that the optimized models perform differently.

Is this a fair experiment? I can't find anything on the subject, since it's so darn hard to explain the issue to Google. Any discussion would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with _fitness_ of a model, you mean the likelihood $p(\text{data} | \textbf{X})$? Ideally, one way to go would be to compute the _Bayes Factor_ between the two hypotheses ($X_0 = 0$ or $X_0 = 1$) by marginalizing (integrating over) all the other parameters of interest, with appropriate priors. This requires the computation of the marginal likelihood for the two cases, which may be computationally expensive.

Comment: I meant some fitness function or objective function, not the likelihood.

Comment: Well, that's zero information -- how do you define fitness? Rather than arbitrary objective functions of a model, if you're doing science (unless you have other goals) you might want to talk in statistical terms which are well defined (e.g., likelihoods), which allow to do things like the one you want to do (e.g., via computation of Bayes factors and marginal likelihoods, or via MCMC over parameter space). If you can't use the likelihood (or approximations thereof, such as in ABC) then it gets into fuzzy territory.

Comment: Not sure if I'm communicating (or understanding you) right, but this is more of a philosophical question, I guess. If you want to isolate the effects of one parameter on a model, shouldn't you fix all other parameters? That is the question. The paper in question used a different method: it optimized all other parameters given fixed values of the parameter in question, and then compared models.

Comment: By the way, we are not trying to fit a model to given data here. We just have a set of possibilities for the model parameters, and each model is then evaluated in terms of its performance (precisely, the model in question is a Liquid State Machine and the objective function is separability between inputs - the greater the separability, the better).

Comment: I see. Well, if instead of maximizing you compute the expectation of the difference in fitness (under some common, meaningful distribution) you end up comparing the fitness in the same way. However, I am not sure that the expectation really gets at what you want since there will be large portions of the parameter space in which performance will be poor, but who cares about those regions. Maybe it'd make sense if you have a distribution of reasonable parameter values. But honestly, if it's an optimization problem people would just maximize.